# What is the CSS selector to parse <style> tag?

Tags: html, qt, css-selectors, webkit

I want to get the content of  element present in HTML page. What is the CSS selector (selector query) That will work to get the element  and its details using

> QWebFram::findAllElements( /*"Need to pass selector query here"*/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#borderimg { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/border.png) 30 round;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The border-image property specifies an image to be used as the border around an element:</p>
<p id="borderimg">Here, the middle sections of the image are repeated to create the border.</p>

<p>Here is the original image:</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 10, and earlier versions, do not support the border-image property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `style` not work for you?

Comment: with "style" CSS selector return the <style> tag, I'm not able to get the internal attribute/valeus of this <style> tag i.e. -webkit-border-image, -o-border-image etc.